# Resolve collision in class names when converting from WSDL to Java

Tags: data-binding, wsdl, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am converting WSDL to Java with CXF. When `-autoNameResolution` key is enabled CXF generates many files with the same content. Is there any way to avoid it?

To avoid nested static classes I've enabled `<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel">`. As you can see in the WSDL element "Apple" is referenced three times. Unfortunately I cannot change WSDL. CXF creates 
*Apple.java, Apple2.java, Apple3.java* accordingly or crashes when `-autoNameResolution` flag is not set.

```html
<xs:element name="Forest">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="99" minOccurs="0" name="Apple">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Size" type="xsd:string" />
            <xs:element name="Color" type="xsd:string" />
            <xs:element name="Taste" type="xsd:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TreeOne">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Branch1" type="xsd:string">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="99" minOccurs="0" name="Apple">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Size" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Color" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Taste" type="xsd:string" />
                </xs:sequence>

              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TreeTwo">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="BranchTwo" type="xsd:string">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="99" minOccurs="0" name="Apple">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Size" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Color" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Taste" type="xsd:string" />
                </xs:sequence>

              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there any way to teach **wsdl2java** not to create *Apple2.java* and Apple3.java and refer to Apple.java in all three cases? With bindings I could change the name to something else like **Apple2->Peach**, **Apple3->Watermelon** but this is not that What I am looking for. It might be obvious to see that all three apples have same set of fields, and are actually the same? 
Is there any way to solve that? May be some refactoring plugin that refactors code generated by cxf?

Answer (score 0):

You can force JAXB/XJC to reuse existing classes using the `jaxb:class/@ref` customization. Something along the lines:

```
<jaxb:class ref="com.acme.foo.Apple"/>
```

Where `com.acme.foo.Apple` is the FQCN of one of the generated `Apple` classes.
Bind this to the other two `xs:complexType`s and JAXB will reuse the existing class instead of generating the same thing again.

I don't have much experience with customizing WSDLs so unfortunatelly I can't point you to the exact syntax of the binding in this case.